# Что такое int argc, char* argv[]?

Tags: c++

Всем привет.
У меня есть код

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    double a;
    double b;
    double f;
    cout << "Enter numbers a, b and f: " << endl;
    cout << "a= ";
    cin >> a;
    cout << "b= ";
    cin >> b;
    cout << "f= ";
    cin >> f;
    cout << "Calculated by the formula: x=(a + b - f / a) + f * a * a - (a + b)\n";
    cout << "x= " << (a + b - f / a) + f * a * a - (a + b) << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

У меня два вопроса. Первое, что такое `int argc`, `char argv[]` и для чего оно используется. А второе, будет ли код работать без `argc`, `char` и т.д?

Comment: http://cppstudio.com/post/421/

Comment: Параметры `main` функции. Если они не используются, то будет https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function